# Exactly what does rpcbind do?

Tags: remote

According to the documentation:

> The rpcbind[3] utility maps RPC services to the ports on which they
>   listen. RPC processes notify rpcbind when they start, registering the
>   ports they are listening on and the RPC program numbers they expect to
>   serve. The client system then contacts rpcbind on the server with a
>   particular RPC program number. The rpcbind service redirects the
>   client to the proper port number so it can communicate with the
>   requested service

To test this, I set up an NFS server and client and
monitored the traffic between them. From what I saw, the client
already knew that the NFS service on the server was listening on port
2049.

So when does rcpbind come into play? When I do `rpcinfo` on the server, I get the following:

```
100003    2    udp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        superuser
100003    3    udp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        superuser
100003    2    udp6      ::.8.1                 nfs        superuser
100003    3    udp6      ::.8.1                 nfs        superuser
100003    2    tcp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        superuser
100003    3    tcp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        superuser
100003    2    tcp6      ::.8.1                 nfs        superuser
100003    3    tcp6      ::.8.1                 nfs        superuser
```

what does `0.0.0.0.8.1` mean in this case? And how does this translate to port 2049?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`rpcbind` is a close analog of BIND, or really, any DNS server. If I recall correctly, you choose or are given a protocol number when you compile the RPC interface's declaration into server and client stub code with `rpcgen`.

When a client signs up for a given interface on a particular host, usually with a `clnt_create()` call, the stub code asks `rpcbind` on that host a question, something like "on what UDP or TCP port is protocol number X listening?" `rpcbind`, unlike most other ONC services, listens on TCP and UDP port 111, so given a host name or IP address, a program can just ask `rpcbind` on that host or IP address. `rpcbind` responds with the appropriate port number, if a server has registered with it on that host. That registration is done by the server process when it calls `svc_create()`.

In your example, the 100003 is the protocol number for NFS. Some process(es) have registered with `rpcbind`, giving their protocol number (100003) and whatever TCP or UDP port they've acquired. It's up to `rpcbind` to correctly give out that port number, 2049 in your case, to any call upon it for "what port should I use for protocol number 100003".

Now we're getting into weirder territory. The "0.0.0.0.8.1" is in the "address" column of `rpcinfo` output. Since that's the "universal address" of the NFS server process, I bet the "0.0.0.0" prefix is the IP address (INADDR_ANY in this case) that the server used in the `bind()` system call when getting a port number. I'm not sure what the "8.1" suffix is, but looking at `rpcinfo` output, it has to have something to do with the NFS server basically being a kernel thread.

Comment: The biggest issue in my case was that I I did not see a query to rcpbind on the server by the client when i was monitoring network traffic. Do you know when this query for the port number happens?

Comment: @SivaDotRender - I'm not 100% certain, but I believe when client code calls clnt_create() to get a handle for the protocol and host. It will probably be done via UDP, unless you set up the whole thing to use TCP.

Comment: "8.1" is the two bytes of the port number. 2049 = (8 * 256) + 1.

Comment: Please stick to the term "program num". As man page does

Comment: "The biggest issue in my case was that I I did not see a query to rcpbind on the server by the client ...."

I know this is late, but NFSv4 doesn't use rpcbind.  Perhaps it was a v4 client?